# What the end of a traversable wormhole looks like?

Tags: general-relativity, wormholes

Looking at the picture below, I assume that the wormhole will have some kind of horizon, either sharp of smooth, and will be about spherical. But in principle we should be able to see the universe from the vantage point of the other end. What does this mapping looks like? Do the far away parts of the universe look as if located at the center of this sphere? and the things closer to the other side's entrance look as closer to the sphere surface? Or may be you only see half of the universe from a given vantage point? I am really lost at this one, I am trying to imagine how the light rays would focus but it does not help me at all.

[image]

Comment: Wow, a negative vote, thanks for your friendly support!

Comment: You may find https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03809 enlightening, esp. fig 7, 9, and 11. Basically, you can see a distorted view of the other side, possible with multiple "reflections".

Comment: @AndersSandberg thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it’s completely theorized, wormholes could hold holographic images inside that allow you to peer through but not physically enter. Or if it is, you may see YOU hurling towards yourself in an inter-dimensional spheroidal reflection.

I’ve pasted a clip you might like and attached the link at the bottom in case you want to check it out.

"Things will look a bit like you're traveling down the center of a wide tunnel", says Butcher. "Directly in front of you you'll see the region of space you're heading to, and behind you is the region you've left behind."

"These views would be surrounded by concentric circularly-distorted repeats of the same view, a bit like an Einstein Ring, with the whole sky (of one end of the wormhole) wrapped into a series of rings that get more and more closely packed together as you move your line-of-sight from the longitudinal direction, to a perpendicular direction."

Credit: Public domain via Les Bossinas (Cortez III Service Corp.) and NASA.

http://physicsbuzz.physicscentral.com/2014/11/what-does-journey-through-wormhole.html?m=1